# 499 ошибка в nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, веб-сервер, fastcgi

Локально ну убунте развернут бэкенд на питоне с nginx с простым конфигом

```
upstream myapp {
    server unix:/tmp/api.sock;
}

server {
    server_name localhost;
    listen      3000;

    location / {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass myapp;
    }
}
```

До сегодняшнего дня все работало нормально. И вдруг ни с того ни с сего клиент перестал получать от сервера ответы. Хотя сам бэкенд их отдает. В логи nginx валятся запросы с 499 ответом. От типа клиента не зависит - пробовал и через браузер и через postman. Почему могла возникнуть такая проблема и как ее решать?

Comment: Время ответа в логах какое? Кто-то посередине рвёт соединение

Comment: @Alex Ten насколько я понимаю - разрывает сразу же `127.0.0.1 - - [05/Apr/2020:18:01:31 +0300] "GET /users/me/ HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.24.0"`

Comment: В дефолтном логе нет времени обработки. Залогируйте $request_time

Comment: @AlexeyTen я вот сейчас осознал, что про 499 ошибку я погорячился. Она возникает, когда я сам закрываю postman, не дождавшись ответа. А так я получаю 504, хотя в дебаггере бэка видно, что запросы обрабатываются правильно и ответы уходят. Но до nginx они как будто не доходят и по лимиту времени я получаю 504.

Comment: А как долго они выполняются?

Comment: @AlexeyTen проблема пропала сама собой так же внезапно как и появилась. Что это было я так и не понял. Спасибо за помощь!